# How to display a simple text dendrogram in terminal?

Tags: python, recursion, text, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to plot some data (groups of countries by their distances) with a simple text dendrogram that would display in my terminal like this:

```
                ---- Monaco
        ----|
                ---- Croatia
            ----|
                ---- Montenegro
    ----|
            ---- Serbia
        ----|
            ---- Slovenia
----|
            ---- Austria
        ----|
                ---- Switzerland
            ----|
                ---- Germany
    ----|
                    ---- Belgium
                ----|
                        ---- Netherlands
                    ----|
                        ---- France
            ----|
                    ---- Sweden
                ----|
                        ---- Denmark
                    ----|
                        ---- Norway
```

I have data stored in a matrix of pairs of clusters with their distances, called `draw_clusters`, and it looks something like this:

```
['Monaco', [[[[['Croatia ', 'Montenegro ', 1.9148542155126762], ['Serbia ', 'Slovenia ', 2.469532658074352], 2.6659130840453282], ['Austria ', ['Switzerland ', 'Germany', 1.8487591643481294], 2.843561940573178], 3.3080033351363003],['...', '...']...[...]]
```

So far I wrote this code, but I don't know how to call the function recursively so that it would plot the text dendrogram into terminal:

```
def draw_dendrogram(draw_clusters):
    for cluster in range(len(draw_clusters)):
        dendrogram(draw_clusters[cluster], 0, 0, 0)

def dendrogram(cluster, x, y, distance):
    node = "|"
    vertical_line = "---"

    print(cluster)
```

Can anyone help me with any tips, because I am new to Python and I am not really sure how the recursion should work?

Comment: Is this a always binary tree? is the third numeric value in every list somehow used? can  you give a shorter but not-truncated example of you matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit confused with the structure of your matrix. So I needed to make some assumptions, like every list represents a binary node, first two values might lead to newer nodes, and 3rd numeric value isn't anyway used in your dendrogram.

If the below is a valid matrix:

```
mat = [
        [   ['Croatia ', 'Montenegro ', 1.9148542155126762],
            ['Serbia ', 'Slovenia ', 2.469532658074352],
            2.6659130840453282],
        ['Austria ',
            ['Switzerland ', 'Germany', 1.8487591643481294],
            2.843561940573178],
        4.5656]
```

You can easily print it's dendrogram with :

```
def print_node(data,spaces = ""):
    if type(data)==type([]):
        print_node(data[0],spaces+" "*5) #here is first recursive call
        print(spaces,"----|")
        print_node(data[1],spaces+" "*5) #second recursive call
    else:
        print(spaces,"----",data)
```

Which will produce an output like this:

```
                ---- Croatia 
           ----|
                ---- Montenegro 
      ----|
                ---- Serbia 
           ----|
                ---- Slovenia 
 ----|
           ---- Austria 
      ----|
                ---- Switzerland 
           ----|
                ---- Germany
```